# Geth settings for watching Events?

Tags: go-ethereum, events

what are the optimal geth settings if you just want to listen to some events that are fired by smart contracts?

I'm having a bit trouble to setup geth properly.

Thanks a lot.

PS: That is my current setup:

```
geth --cache=1024 --syncmode=fast --rpc --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal,net,network,debug,txpool" --ws --wsorigins="*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me:

```
geth --testnet --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8546 --wsorigins * --cache 512 --rpc --wsapi "eth,net,web3,network,debug,txpool" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,network,debug,txpool" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --fast
```

It's listening both on rpc and ws, but you can only use ws if you want.

Then, there are two things to know about listening to events with web3 1.0:

1. Event subscription won't show past events. If you need past events, use this:

   `YourContract.getPastEvents('YourEventName', { fromBlock: 0 }, (error, events) => {})`
2. You can listen for new events like this:

   `TokenContract
     .events
     .Transfer({
       from: 0,
       to: 'latest',
     })
     .on('data', event => console.log('data', event));`